# How do you find the pole of an irregularly shaped spherical mirror?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

I know that pole is the geometric centre of a spherical mirror. But how do you really find it for an irregularly cut mirror in real life?

Answer (score 0):

The pole of a mirror is the point where the axis meets the mirror.
If your irregularly cut mirror is a paraboloid, it has an identifiable axis -- so wherever that axis intersects the mirror would be the pole.

If the irregularly cut mirror is spherical, then it will not have a unique axis.  In that case, any point on the mirror could reasonably be called the pole.